# Is it possible to attach BeanPostProcessor with specific bean initilzation

Tags: spring

I am wondering if it is possible to define a `BeanPostProcessor` class which can only be executed for specific beans.

As per configuration, I can have 2 beans like as mentioned below. Here `InitHelloWorld` is implementing `BeanPostProcessor`. `postProcessBeforeInitialization` and `postProcessAfterInitialization` methods are overwritten here. These methods gets called for all the bean initialized. I want these methods being called only for `com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld`

```
 <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld"
           init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
           <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
       </bean>

<bean id="helloWorld1" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld1"
           init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
           <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
       </bean>

       <bean class="com.tutorialspoint.InitHelloWorld" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use some `marker` annotation on those classes:

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException { 
   Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean);
   if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanClass, MyMarker.class) != null) {
       ....
       return bean;
    }

   return bean;
}
```

Comment: This is the right way. Spring also uses the same approach with Aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the class itself when defining the method something like:

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException { 
    if (bean.getClass().equals(HelloWorld.class)) {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new FieldCallback() { 
        ......
    }
```

Comment: Over the period of time there will be alot of conditions like this. So I would like to avoid using this. Also doing so will be one more problem as I need to revisit this file again and again if I delete any bean from app.

Comment: So i would suggest you inject a property in property file and check beanName with beans defined in a property.

Answer (score 0):

A simple if-statement that checks the class instance in the postProcessor initialization will do the trick, that is:

```
if (bean instanceof HelloWorld){...}
```

or

```
if (bean.getClass().equals(HelloWorld.class)){...}
```

To put it in context:

```
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof HelloWorld){
        System.out.println("This only prints for an instance of HelloWord");
    }
```